# Assets not found rails 4 + Capistrano 3 + Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, capistrano3, puma

I am deployed my rails project to the AWS. I have following in my `Gemfile`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end
```

In my `production.rb`

```
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

However, when I load my application in the web browser I see in the console that my `application-xxxxxx.css` and `application-xxxxxx.js` gives `404 not found` error. Also, when I go to the server and look for the file in public/assets/ folder, the application-xxxxxx.js is present there.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The only log that I can see is 
`<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>` for application-xxxxxxx.css

Comment: did you run bundle exec rake assets:precompile?? after deploy

Comment: I don't need to do it, because the assets in the server are already visible at public/assets/application-xxxxxx.js and css. Capistrano is doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not in the asset compilation and deployment. I had to change the path from `root /home/deploy/portal/public;` to `/home/deploy/portal/current/public;` in nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.